# How to ignore certain files from dry run (note -n) of p4 clean using this command `p4 clean -Idealn`?

Tags: perforce

I do have a `.p4ignore` file. This file contains names of certain temp files e.g. `tags`, `cscope.files`, etc. For adding all files in current folder using this command `p4 add ...`; this `.p4ignore` file works. Thus temp files are not added in p4. But if I want to see dry run of p4 clean using this command `p4 clean -Idealn ...`; `.p4ignore` file is not coming into picture. How to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using all those extra flags?  Extra flags don't make the command work better, just differently (and one of the differences is skipping your ignore file...)

Answer (score 1):

From `p4 help clean`:

```
    The -I flag informs the client that it should not perform any ignore
    checking configured by P4IGNORE.
```

The `.p4ignore` file isn't "coming into the picture" because you've specifically excluded it; what you're asking how to do is simply the default behavior, i.e. to not attempt to "clean" extra files if they're ignored.  Remove the `-I` flag and that will fix your problem.

The `-ade` flags are pointless if you're using them all together; the default behavior is already to clean all files (which is what you want to do), so you only need to use one of those flags if you want to target specific operations (e.g. you'd use `clean -a` to only clean "added" files but skip "edited" and "deleted" files).  Remove those too.

Just run:

```
p4 clean -l -n
```

If you prefer seeing absolute paths to your files (the default), you can omit the `-l` flag as well.